# matlab how to turn image 90 degree?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, reshape

I have 100 gray images (256*256 pixels) and they are stored in faces.mat file.
So in the faces.mat file, there are 100 rows and 65536(256*256) columns.
Each row represents one image.

Now I want to reshape the faces matrix and showed the images.

I use:

```
for i=1:N    
    imagesc(reshape(faces(i,:)'),256,256));
    colormap gray;
end
```

But I found my image turn 90 degree!
[image]

Could someone tell me how to turn the image right? Did I process images wrong when I turn them into face.mat? Below is the code I wrote to store images to matrix.

```
function ImageGenerate
Files = dir(strcat('D:\face\','*.tiff'));
LengthFiles = length(Files);
faces = [];
for i = 1:LengthFiles;
    Img = imread(strcat('D:\face\',Files(i).name));
    temp = im2double(Img);
    [row, col] = size(temp);
    vector = [];
    for i =1 : row
        for j = 1:col
            vector = [vector temp(i,j)];
        end
    end
    faces = [faces;vector];
end
save('faces2.mat','faces');
```

Comment: You really did make your life more difficult by the way you stored the images - see my answer for an explanation (and a better approach).

Comment: It appears rotated using imagesc. Use imshow to display images correctly otherwise you can either rotate the image.

Comment: If you do `vector = temp(:)`, you won’t have this problem (and it’ll be a lot faster). You are actively transposing the image when you convert it to a tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) to rotate images. To rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise, simply write

```
img = reshape(faces(i,:)'),256,256);
img = imrotate(img, 90);
```

Comment: I tried B = imrotate(imagesc(reshape(faces(2,:),256,256)),90), imshow(B)  but it doesn't work. I don't know why

Answer (score 5):

For rotating images with int multipliers of 90 degrees there is [`rot90`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) function:

```
rot90(Img);
```

This is more efficient than [`imrotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123859/1714410) and more general than [just transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130800/1714410) that were proposed in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For people who don't have the image processing toolbox, the same thing can be achieved by applying a transpose (which flips X and Y) followed by a reflection about the X axis:

```
img = reshape(faces(i,:), [256 256]);
rightImg = flipdim(img', 1);
```

By the way, I believe you could have saved yourself a lot of trouble by changing the code that writes the faces, as follows:

```
temp = im2double(Img);
faces = [faces;temp(:)];
```

At that point, you would have stored all the voxels in the image in the right sequence, and could have addressed an individual image with

```
fre = reshape(faces,[256 256 100]);
img = fre(:,:,ii);
```

To understand why this works you have to realize that Matlab stores elements in the array in the order of the elements - so m(1,1), m(2,1), m(3,1), m(1,2), m(2,2), ... etc. The way I did this preserves the order of the pixels in the image, so all I have to do at the end is reshape the matrix and recover the ith face.

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is represented as a matrix of values you can just transpose the matrix therefore imgNew=img';

**Example:**

```
  load mandrill
  X2=X';
  figure()
  image(X);
  colormap(map)
  figure()
  image(X2)
  colormap(map)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice - with your method you end up with a left/right flip, not just a rotation; you can understand this is true by thinking about transposition as a reflection about the diagonal, so you create a "mirror image" and you need to do something to get back to the "right" image. Look at the corner of the baboon's eyes...